# How start site to browse through appcmd.exe?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-7, appcmd

How start site to browse through appcmd.exe? How know site url through appcmd.exe?

Upd: My site have name to iis: Default Web Site, but at start on brawse have address ht_tp://localhost/Site. How me define name "localhost"?

Comm. "start" to appcmd starting site. I want open site to browse, how make it?

Answer (score 0):

> The Site object provides methods to list, create and delete site
>   instances (these are standard methods that are present on almost all
>   objects), as well as stop and start sites. Each site instance in turn
>   will contain properties, such as site name and site id, that can be
>   inspected, searched for, or set. The output of each command is always
>   a list of object instances.

Take a look here: [Getting Started with AppCmd.exe](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#Working)

Futher help can be found by command:

> APPCMD /?

Comment: MeNoMore: my site have name to iis: Default Web Site, but at start on brawse have address htt_p://localhost/Site. How me define name "localhost"? 

Comm. "start" to appcmd starting site. I want open site to browse, how make it?